# Address not updating in while placing order

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

[image]

I am updating the address at the time of checkout, but when the order has been completed with Sagepay the address field both shipping and billing goes blank in Magento admin.

Its working ok with test mode and when i go to live mode its throwing this blank address in admin.

Comment: please post code so that we can trace out what problem you are facing

Comment: @amit can you mention what do you mean by test mode and live mode? Is it payment gateway mode or something else

Comment: @Muk Yes its a test mode for Sagepay payment gateway.

Comment: @amitnaraniwal If there is an option to create logs with this payment method enable it and check the messages.

Comment: @Muk i tried but there is no error log created.